# How to force angular to create the property in html when using bind

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I need angular to create the property in my html when I use a 'property binding', but angular only creates it when I write the value directly in the html.

I left a very basic example on stackBlitz, a 'button' component that receives the `primary` or `secondary` type and depending on the type of the button it changes the color correctly, but when I check the element, the property is not created `typeButton` on the button that uses the `property binding` and in my real application I need this property to be created in the html.

link stackBlitz: [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ypcu6m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fbutton%2Fbutton.component.ts,src%2Fbutton%2Fbutton.component.html,src%2Fbutton%2Fbutton.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fbutton%2Fbutton.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,test%2Fstyle-min.css,test%2Fstyle.core.css,angular.json,src%2Findex.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it:

```
@Component({
 ...
 host: {
  '[attr.typeButton]': 'typeButton',
 },
})
```

for example:
https://angular.io/guide/accessibility#case-study-building-a-custom-progress-bar

Comment: its work!!! tks Rafael

Answer (score 1):

Edit :

Please try this for the attribute binding :

```js
@HostBinding('attr.typeButton')
@Input('typeButton')
typeButton: string;
```

You are not looking at the right place.
The first button is showing a `property` because there is hardcoded Input value. So it looks like a "regular" property. But actually, the property is indeed binded in both the `button` in the HTML by Angular @Input :

[image]

So basically, I'd say that Angular does what is expected from him, it's placing the attribute in the button like so : `[attr.typeButton]="typeButton"`

The first button is not "responding" to the changes because the value is hardcoded.

Cheers
Alain

Comment: Hi Alain, thanks for the reply. I know the property is created on the "button", but as I said in the question I need the property to be created on the "po-button". Why does Angular create for one and not create for the other?

Comment: Well it doesn't really create it, it's seen as a property because it's plain HTML so to speak, but the `[typebutton]` is not considered as an attribute. I edited my answer to place the attribute on the Host component.